# Subscribing to comments on another persons question

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications

On meta.movies.SE we tend to have longer discussions in question comments about an issue. Sometimes comments will come in days or weeks later, and unless you are the person who posted the question, you don't have any chance to be informed about new contributions to the discussion. So my only option is to check on old questions regularly to see if anyone posted anything new in the comments section.

The @-syntax only helps if its a discussion between two persons (which most often it is not).

**It would be great if it were possible to subscribe to comments on any question, not just your own.**

This could either be done automatically when you "favorite" a question, or explicitly through a new button.

I guess this could be limited to the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag on meta sites, but might be helpful in other cases as well.

### EDIT

To clarify: The reason I would need something like this is not for discussions in normal questions. This is about discussions in **meta site [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions**.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Exchange is a Question and Answer site. It isn't a Discussion site. That's more suited to forums (of which there are plenty of).

Comments there there for requesting clarification / providing critique of a question/answer, not for having a conversation. Providing this facility would basically condone the use of the site for conducting and following discussion topics, and as a result I am against this. Plenty of forums do that sort of thing far better than the StackExchange model is built to do.

Keep Stack Exchange for asking Questions and getting Answers. Leave the discussion topics to discussion forums.

Comment: So you say discussions on site metas are bad?

Comment: BTW I totally agree on this view regarding normal questions on sites themselves, but meta questions with the [discussion] tag are somewhat of a special case for me. Sometimes you just have to discuss all aspects of a question further before you can find an appropriate answer

Comment: Discussions *about* a question on meta are fine, but not discussions about a *topic* that a question is about. (I.E. it's OK to discuss "why was this question about movie plots closed?" but it's not OK to discuss various plots themselves).

Comment: When I said _topics_, I meant topics like "Should we allow identify-this-movie questions on our site?", not topics like a movie itself. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @JonW Well, I doubt anyone would discuss something like that in a meta-question anyway, that seems completely out of the question and rather unrelated to the problem adressed here. Of course nobody wants to transform SE into a forum, but more often than not you can't discuss and respond to every kind of answer with an answer again and there necessarily happens to be some (important and fruitful) discussion in the comments, especially in hard to decide meta discussions. But I also see that we might just be doing meta the wrong way.

Comment: @ChristianRau: My answer was left before the question itself had been clarified as relating to meta questions.

Comment: @JonW I see, I wasn't adressing the answer so much, but your comment.

Comment: @JonW To be fair, even before my edit I was specifically talking about "meta.movies.SE". ;)